# Spring Zero Copy file download

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, zero-copy

I have to write a Web service that will be hit by a web application to download image.Image URL is not directly exposed to client, it will be be decided by some business logic. I am using Amazon S3 for file storage so how can i implement zero copy file transfer with spring?